# Error: Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

Tags: android, eclipse, find

I have this problem on Android application. Here is the code of the project

***Manifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapbcb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
            android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapbcb.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapbcb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="API_KEY"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***Main.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

***Java***

```
package com.example.mapbcb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When compiled, shows the error:

```
Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
```

The API_KEY was generated in my computer and is correct.

Help me, please!!

Comment: "When compile show the error: Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings" -- no, it does not. First, that is a runtime error, not a compile-time error. Second, it is not related to your problem.

Comment: I removed your key from the code, no need to show it everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your application to `minSDK 8` but you are using the `MapFragment` object which is supported only from `SDK 11`.

what you should do instead is to use `SupportMapFragment` object and a `FragmentAcitivity`.

another problem in your code is that your permissions:

```
 <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapbcb.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

should contain your project package: `com.example.mapbcb` instead of: `com.example.mapdemo`

Take a look at this blog I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps API V2 to support older versions of the Android platform using the `google-support-v4` library:

[Google Maps API v2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)